# NextJS refactoring API route from SSR to SSG

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, ssg, static-site-generation

I have a SSR API that I want convert to SSG to generate it at build time

**/pages/api/dostuff/[cid].tsx**

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { cid } = req.query;
  let data;
  data = await doStuff(cid);
  res.status(200).json(data)
}
```

My approach has been to start implementing **getStaticPaths** as follows:

```
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {

  return {
    paths: [
      { params: {"cid": "AAA"} },      
      { params: {"cid": "BBB"} },      
    ],
    fallback: false // false or 'blocking'
  };
}
```

But than I stopped because I couldn't find a viable option of implementing **getStaticProps** in order to have SSG.

I would have proceeded like follow

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {

  const { cid } = context.params.cid;
  let data;
  data = await doStuff(cid);
  return { props: { data } };

}
```

Should I create a component that just outputs plain JSON?
This doesn't look right to me; what's the best approach ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Why are you trying to use `getStaticProps`/`getStaticPaths` for an API route? Those are used to generate static pages. What's the issue with the current API route?

Comment: I want to generate a static API, if that makes sense: I dont't want it to be called each time a request arrives and misses the cache.
I'd like to have it called only once at build time.
I could probably just make a script and fetch it at build time, but I hoped that the same approach for pages could be used for APIs too

Comment: _"I could probably just make a script and fetch it at build time"_ - I believe that's what you should do.